# Cmdlet verbose stream

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm currently writing a C# cmdlet using the PowerShell 5.0 SDK.

I'm trying to pipe the StandardError of a third party executable to the cmdlet output when run from powershell in "real time".

I'm currently using the MedallionShell library to handle running the process. I've tried this with a normal C# win form and used the Command.StandardError.PipeToAsync(Console.OpenStandardOutput()) to get the output to print as the executable generated it to the console in "real time".

I tried to create my own Stream object that calls WriteVerbose but it didn't seem to print anything to the powershell screen (I am passing -Verbose to cmdlet when I run it).

My current flow looks something like this:

1. Open Powershell ISE
2. Load my module (C# dll)
3. Call my cmdlet with parameters

   - Command.Run
   - Command.StandardError.PipeToAsync(???)
   - Command.Wait (During this step, output should be flowing to powershell window)
   - Check Command.Result.Success.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: Did your own `Stream` implementation call `WriteVerbose` directly or marshal them to pipeline thread?

Comment: My implementation of the stream took the cmdlet and used it to call WriteVerbose. The bytes I received from the Write call, I converted to a string using the Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes).

Comment: It is not what I am asking. You can not just call `WriteVerbose` on arbitrary thread. So, did you marshal calls to `WriteVerbose` back to pipeline thread?

Comment: No I didn't, how do you marshal the call back to the pipeline thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not just call `Cmdlet`'s `Write` methods (like `WriteVerbose`) from arbitrary thread. You need to marshal calls to this methods back to pipeline thread. A way to do that is to implement message loop, which would process messages from others threads, when other threads want to invoke something in pipeline thread.

```
Add-Type @‘
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Concurrent;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Management.Automation;
    using System.Threading;
    [Cmdlet(VerbsLifecycle.Invoke, "Process")]
    public class InvokeProcessCmdlet : Cmdlet {
        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        [Parameter(Position = 2)]
        public string Arguments { get; set; }
        protected override void EndProcessing() {
            using(BlockingCollection<Action> messageQueue = new BlockingCollection<Action>()) {
                using(Process process = new Process {
                    StartInfo=new ProcessStartInfo(FileName, Arguments) {
                        UseShellExecute=false,
                        RedirectStandardOutput=true,
                        RedirectStandardError=true
                    },
                    EnableRaisingEvents=true
                }) {
                    int numberOfCompleteRequests = 0;
                    Action complete = () => {
                        if(Interlocked.Increment(ref numberOfCompleteRequests)==3) {
                            messageQueue.CompleteAdding();
                        }
                    };
                    process.OutputDataReceived+=(sender, args) => {
                        if(args.Data==null) {
                            complete();
                        } else {
                            messageQueue.Add(() => WriteObject(args.Data));
                        }
                    };
                    process.ErrorDataReceived+=(sender, args) => {
                        if(args.Data==null) {
                            complete();
                        } else {
                            messageQueue.Add(() => WriteVerbose(args.Data));
                        }
                    };
                    process.Exited+=(sender, args) => complete();
                    process.Start();
                    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
                    foreach(Action action in messageQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
                        action();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
’@ -PassThru | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Assembly | Import-Module
```

And you can test it with something like this:

```
Invoke-Process icacls 'C:\* /c' -Verbose
```

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, I made the assumption the WriteVerbose would know how to handle the call no matter where I was. However I don't fully understand your code example, mainly the variable 'numberOfCompleteRequests', the 'complete' action, and the foreach. Does the foreach run forever until the 'CompleteAdding' is called? What's the purpose of the ==3 check?

Comment: @AbdulKhan *Does the foreach run forever until the 'CompleteAdding' is called?* — Yes. *the 'complete' action* — I do want to not repeat the code, but I also want to have access to local variables `messageQueue` and `numberOfCompleteRequests`, so I define `complete` with lambda expression to have closure over local variables. *What's the purpose of the ==3 check?* — There are 3 events I want to occur before continue: output stream closed, error stream closed and process exit, so I check that `complete()` called 3 times. You can choose different set of events, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much, that explanation helped me write a version of your message loop suited for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you derive from `PSCmdlet` instrad of `Cmdlet` you will have access to `this.Host.UI.WriteVerboseLine` which can be called from any thread **at your own risk** (i think it doesn't prevents in any way that the outputed string will be mixed in the wrong way) 
Anyway, in my experience it have always worked well so far, and if the cmdlet is something that only you will consume i think the risk may be acceptable.

Again, it works well if used in a console, i don't know if it behaves the intended way if you later on redirect the verbose stream somewhere else than the console or something that doesn't have a "UI"

For sure @PetSerAl solution is more appropriate if you have some more time to implement it